# Como usar las variables protegidas en GitLab

Tags: gitlab

Tengo mi proyecto en GitLab. Este proyecto tiene un fichero de `settings.yml` donde aparece la url de conexión a la bbdd, usuario y contraseña. De tal modo como:

```
database_conn:      'pgsql:host=url.com;dbname=db_name'
database_user:      'usuario'
database_password:  'seguridad_maxima'
```

**Esto cambia depende del entorno de producción y desarrollo. Para cada uno tengo diferentes valores.**

Cuando se hace `merge` a desarrollo se ejecuta `gitlab-ci.yml` y lo mismo a producción. En esas ejecuciones es cuando deberían ser cambiadas.

Algo como

```
database_conn:      $VARIABLE_DESARROLLO_URL_DATABASE
database_user:      $VARIABLE_DESARROLLO_USUARIO_DATABASE
database_password:  $VARIABLE_DESARROLLO_PASSWORD_DATABASE
```

Y establecer estas variables en el `gitlab_ci.yml`

```
deploy-to-desarrollo:
   variables:
      $VARIABLE_DESARROLLO_URL_DATABASE:      'pgsql:host=url.com;dbname=db_name'
      $VARIABLE_DESARROLLO_USUARIO_DATABASE:   'usuario'
      $VARIABLE_DESARROLLO_PASSWORD_DATABASE:  'seguridad_maxima'
```

Alguna idea de como se utiliza?